# Powershell Start-Process command parameter escaping

Tags: powershell

I try to open an elevated powershell from within a powershell session.
This works:

```
powershell -NoExit -Command "Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList @('-NoExit','-NoProfile') -Verb RunAs"
```

This does not:

```
powershell -NoExit -Command "Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList @(`"-NoExit`",`"-NoProfile`") -Verb RunAs"
```

The error says:

```
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:49
+ Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList @(-NoExit,-NoProfile) -Verb Ru ...
+                                                 ~
Argument in der Parameterliste fehlt.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument
```

So somehow the quotes get lost. Why?

Comment: The first line works perfect, the second line does not differ from the first one except for other quotes on different locations. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to start a subshell with elevated rights. The point of this question is about why the quotes get stripped off in one case but not the other.